# How to make a functional Component in react and use destructive assignment? (I wrote some code but not working)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

How do i make this into destructive assignment?

because it keeps giving me an error of

`Binding element 'onClickBackDrop' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong

```
import React from "react";

import "../assets/stylesheets/BackDrop.css";

export default function BackDrop(props: any) {
  const {onClickBackDrop()} = props;
  return <div className="cs-backdrop" onClick={props.onClickBackDrop()} />;
}
```

```
import React, { FC } from 'react'

interface BackDropProps  { 
  onClickBackDrop: Function 
}

const BackDrop: FC<BackDropProps> = (props) => {
  const { onClickBackDrop } = props;
  return (
    <div className="cs-backdrop" onClick={()=>onClickBackDrop()} />
  )
}


export default BackDrop;
```

I was told to write the code like this

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run your function everywhere it used. also you can use destructive assignment in function component parameter.

```
import React from "react";

import "../assets/stylesheets/BackDrop.css";

export default function BackDrop({ onClickBackDrop }) {
  return <div className="cs-backdrop" onClick={onClickBackDrop} />;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `(props: {onClickBackDrop: () => void})` or `({onClickBackDrop}:{onClickBackDrop: () => void})`. You can omit type annotation but is bad in typescript.

and you probably want to use

```
<div ... onClick={onClickBackDrop} />
```

or

```
<div ... onClick={() => onClickBackDrop()} />
```

Please ignore my correction if onClickBackDrop indeed returns another function.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it this way:

```
import React from "react";


export default function BackDrop({ onClickBackDrop }) {
  return <div className="cs-backdrop" onClick={onClickBackDrop()} />;
}
```